# \xrightarrow not changing size with \scriptstyle and \scriptscriptstyle

Tags: math-mode, arrows, scaling, newtxmath

Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        v\xrightarrow{e}w &\quad v\overset{e}\rightarrow w \\
        \scriptstyle v\xrightarrow{e}w &\quad \scriptstyle v\overset{e}\rightarrow w \\
        \scriptscriptstyle v\xrightarrow{e}w &\quad \scriptscriptstyle v\overset{e}\rightarrow w
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: xrightarrow not scaling]

While `\rightarrow` is changing in size when using `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle`, `\xrightarrow` is not and produces arrows of wrong size and hence height, as well as too little spacing.

Is there a way to fix `\xrightarrow`?

Comment: You might want to reduce the MWE even further and removing the `libertine` stuff as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to its definition, `\xrightarrow` only provides normal size and it won't scale in subscripts.

You can define a (less efficient) variant:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{libertine}
%\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\newcommand{\sxrightarrow}[2][]{%
  \mathrel{\text{$\xrightarrow[#1]{#2}$}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
v\sxrightarrow{e}w &\quad v\overset{e}\rightarrow w \\
\scriptstyle v\sxrightarrow{e}w &\quad \scriptstyle v\overset{e}\rightarrow w \\
\scriptscriptstyle v\sxrightarrow{e}w &\quad \scriptscriptstyle v\overset{e}\rightarrow w
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the bottom-most "e" on the right-hand side is larger than its companion on the left.  more like the size of the one above it in the second row.  (in the first and second rows, the sizes match.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's because there is no third level for subscripts/superscripts. I don't think such an arrow would be used in scriptscriptstyle, but the smaller label is better anyway.